# Extracting values from a dataset column based on key from a different column

Tags: dataset

Take a small dataset, for example a sample of the Titanic data:

```
ds=Dataset@{<|"PassengerId" -> 1, "Survived" -> 0, "Pclass" -> 3, 
"Name" -> "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", "Sex" -> "male", "Age" -> 22, 
"SibSp" -> 1, "Parch" -> 0, "Ticket" -> "A/5 21171", "Fare" -> 7.25,
 "Cabin" -> "", "Embarked" -> "S"|>, <|"PassengerId" -> 2, 
"Survived" -> 1, "Pclass" -> 1, 
"Name" -> "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", 
"Sex" -> "female", "Age" -> 38, "SibSp" -> 1, "Parch" -> 0, 
"Ticket" -> "PC 17599", "Fare" -> 71.2833, "Cabin" -> "C85", 
"Embarked" -> "C"|>, <|"PassengerId" -> 3, "Survived" -> 1, 
"Pclass" -> 3, "Name" -> "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", 
 "Sex" -> "female", "Age" -> 26, "SibSp" -> 0, "Parch" -> 0, 
"Ticket" -> "STON/O2. 3101282", "Fare" -> 7.925, "Cabin" -> "", 
"Embarked" -> "S"|>, <|"PassengerId" -> 4, "Survived" -> 1, 
"Pclass" -> 1, 
"Name" -> "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", 
"Sex" -> "female", "Age" -> 35, "SibSp" -> 1, "Parch" -> 0, 
"Ticket" -> 113803, "Fare" -> 53.1, "Cabin" -> "C123", 
"Embarked" -> "S"|>, <|"PassengerId" -> 5, "Survived" -> 0, 
"Pclass" -> 3, "Name" -> "Allen, Mr. William Henry", 
"Sex" -> "male", "Age" -> 35, "SibSp" -> 0, "Parch" -> 0, 
"Ticket" -> 373450, "Fare" -> 8.05, "Cabin" -> "", 
"Embarked" -> "S"|>}
```

I want to extract, for example, the age of a particular passenger. I can group by name:

```
 dsName=ds[GroupBy["Name"]]
```

But trying to extract the age of a given passenger with

```
dsName[["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina","Age"]]
```

results in an error message. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dsName[["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", All,"Age"]]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
dsName["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", All,"Age"]

dsName["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"][All,"Age"]

ds[Select[#"Name"=="Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"&], "Age"]

ds[Select[#"Name" == "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina" &]][All, "Age"]
```

Comment: Do you know why the method I tried does not work?

Comment: @Whelp, if you look at the target row using `dsName[["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"]]// Normal` you see that it is of the form `{<|key1 -> value1,...|>}`(your method would have worked if this were  `<|key1 -> value1,...|>`) ; so we need to use `All` (`1` would have worked too) to get all elements in  this added dimension.

Comment: You can also `Transpose` the dataset after your `GroupBy` so that the levels are what you'd expect. `dsName = ds[GroupBy["Name"], Transpose]`, and then you can do `dsName["Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", "Age"]` as you'd expect